# How to create a custom container for range-v3

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, range-v3

I understood how to create my own range-v3 *views* using `view-facade`, but now I would like to create my own *container* so I can use in-place-mutating `actions`:

```
MyContainer<ItemType> list = createList();
list |= ranges::actions::transform(&someMappingFunction);
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be no simple helper like a `container-facade` and my C++ skills are not mad enough yet to understand the range-v3 source by just reading it. Which interface does my container need to implement, or what does it need to be derived from?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of range-v3, a Range is a Container if `begin` on a mutable instance returns a different type than on a const instance, or if `is_view<T>::value` is `false`. The actions often require additional capabilities. For instance, many require `cont.insert(pos, val)` for inserting value `val` into container `cont` at position `pos`. Some require `cont.erase(from, to)` for removing elements denoted by the range [`from`,`to`). Apologies for the lack of documentation. HTH.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, but I guess it's just too difficult for me to see the general interface of a range in the template-heavy source of range-v3. Could you please sketch in your answer a very minimal implementation of a dummy range/container that just shows what has to be overridden to make it work? Or is there something explicit like this already hidden in the range-v3 source, tests, examples or elsewhere? Thanks again

Comment: Wait... is it true that I can just implement a STL compatible container + iterator and it'll work as an input and output range?

Comment: Your container should have const and non-const begin/end, and (depending on what you want to do) an insert member that takes a position and a value, and an erase member that takes two iterators. That should make most (all?) of the actions work. I can't check right now, sorry.